# Connection reset by peer [Errno 104] in Python

Tags: python, sockets, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, python-multithreading

I have witten a distributed program. Every node (Virtual machine) in the network sends data (through outgoing connection) to and receives data (through incomming connection) from every other node. Before sending data, all nodes has opend a socket to every other node (including the single source node). After a delay of 3 seconds the source starts sending a different file chunk to each of other nodes in the network. Every node starts forwarding the receiveing chunk after arrival of the first packet.

The programs finishes successfully for multiple times without any error. But, sometimes one random node reset the incomming connections (while still sends data through its outgoing connections).

Each node has both n-2 sender threads and n-1 receiver threads.

Sending Function:

```
def relaySegment_Parallel(self):
        connectionInfoList = []
        seenSegments = []
        readyServers = []
        BUFFER_SIZE = Node.bufferSize
        while len(readyServers) < self.connectingPeersNum-len(Node.sources) and self.isMainThreadActive(): #Data won't be relayed to the sources
            try:
                tempIp = None
                for ip in Node.IPAddresses:
                    if ip not in readyServers and ip != self.ip and ip not in self.getSourcesIp():
                        tempIp = ip
                        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                        s.connect((ip, Node.dataPort))
                        connectionInfoList.append((s, ip))
                        readyServers.append(ip)
                        if Node.debugLevel2Enable:
                            print "RelayHandler: Outgoing connection established with IP:  " + str(ip)
            except socket.error, v:
                errorcode = v[0]
                if  errorcode == errno.ECONNRESET:
                    print "(RelayHandler) Connection reset ! Node's IP: " + str(tempIp)
                if errorcode == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
                    print "(RelayHandler) Node " + str(tempIp) + " are not ready yet!"
                continue
            except:
                print "Error: Cannot connect to IP: " + str (tempIp)
                continue
            print "(RelayHandler) Ready to relay data to " + str(len(readyServers)) + " numeber of servers."
        try:
            pool = ThreadPool(processes = Node.threadPoolSize)
            while Node.terminateFlag == 0 and not self.isDistributionDone() and self.isMainThreadActive():
                if len(self.toSendTupleList) > 0:
                    self.toSendLock.acquire()
                    segmentNo, segmentSize, segmentStartingOffset, data = self.toSendTupleList.pop(0)
                    self.toSendLock.release()
                    if len(data) > 0:
                        if segmentNo not in seenSegments:
                            #Type: 0 = From Sourece , 1 = From Rlayer
                            #Sender Type/Segment No./Segment Size/Segment Starting Offset/
                            tempList = []
                            for s, ip in connectionInfoList:
                                tempData = "1/" + str(self.fileSize) + "/"  + str(segmentNo) + "/" + str(segmentSize) + "/" + str(segmentStartingOffset) + "/"
                                tempList.append((s, ip, tempData))
                            pool.map(self.relayWorker, tempList)
                            seenSegments.append(segmentNo)
                        relayList = []
                        for s, ip in connectionInfoList:
                            relayList.append((s, ip, data))
                        pool.map(self.relayWorker, relayList)
            for s, ip in connectionInfoList:
                s.shutdown(1)# 0:Further receives are disallowed -- 1: Further  sends are disallow / sends -- 2: Further sends and receives are disallowed.
                s.close()
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
        except socket.error, v:
            errorcode=v[0]
            if errorcode==errno.ECONNREFUSED:
                print "(RelayHandler) Error: Connection Refused in RelaySegment function. It can not connect to: ", ip
            else:
                print "\n(RelayHandler) Error1 in relaying segments (Parallel) to ", ip, " !!! ErrorCode: ", errorcode
            traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
        except:
            print "\n(RelayHandler) Error2 in relaying segments (Parallel) to ", ip
            traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
```

Receiving Function:

```
def receiveDataHandler(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)# Allows us to resue the port immediately after termination of the program
            s.bind((self.ip, Node.dataPort))
            s.listen(Node.MaxNumClientListenedTo)
            threadsList = []
            fHandler = fileHandler(self.inFileAddr, Node.bufferSize)
            isStart = False
            executionTime = 0
            connectedPeersSofar = 0
            while (not self.connectingPeersNum == connectedPeersSofar)  and  self.isMainThreadActive() and Node.terminateFlag == 0 and not self.isReceptionDone():
                conn, ipAddr = s.accept()
                thread_receiveData = Thread2(target = self.receiveData_Serial, args = (conn, ipAddr, fHandler))
                thread_receiveData.start()
                if Node.debugLevel2Enable:
                    print 'Receive Handler: New thread started for connection from address:', ipAddr
                connectedPeersSofar += 1
                threadsList.append(thread_receiveData)
                if isStart == False:
                    isStart = True
            print "(RecieiverHandeler) Receiver stops listening: Peers Num "+str(self.connectingPeersNum) +i " connected peers so far: " + str(connectedPeersSofar)
            for i in range(0, len(threadsList)):
                self.startTime = threadsList[i].join()
            if isStart:
                executionTime = float(time.time()) - float(self.startTime)
            else:
                print "\n\t No Start! Execution Time: --- 0 seconds ---" , "\n"
            s.shutdown(2)# 0:Further receives are disallowed -- 1: Further  sends are disallow / sends -- 2: Further sends and receives are disallowed.
            s.close()
            return executionTime
        except socket.error, v:
            errorcode = v[0]
            if errorcode == 22: # 22: Invalid arument
                print "Error: Invalid argument in connection acceptance (receive data handler)"
            elif errorcode==errno.ECONNREFUSED:
                print "Error: Connection Refused in receive"
            else:
                print "Error1 in Data receive Handler !!! ErrorCode: ", errorcode
            traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
        except:
            print "Error2 in Data receive Handler !!!"
            traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
```

The Sending thread of all nodes prints that the node is connected to all other nodes (including the random malfunctioning node). However, the Receiving function of the random node waits on

> s.accept()

and does not accept any connection but the connection from the single source which is the last one to connect. The random node just wait without raising any exception.

It seems that

> s.listen()

(TCP protocole) of the random node makes the senders think that they are connected, while

> s.accept()

does not accept any one but the last one. Then, for some reason it resets the conneciton, and that is why others (senders) raise the "Connection reset by peer" exception when they try to send data. The only sender that finishes its job without any error is the sources which is the last one to connect.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/DCDataDistribution/Node.py", line 137, in relayWorker
socketConn.sendall(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Why is that happening?

FYI:
I am running my program on Amazon EC2 instances. The type of each instance is t2.micro (1 vCPU, 2.5 GHz, Intel Xeon Family (Up to 3.3 GHz) and, 1 GiB memory). The Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM) is running on every instances.

Comment: Not enough code here to diagnose and your explanation is a bit hard to follow. Just as a guess, I'd suspect your "random" receiving node is closing the wrong socket, resulting in the `ECONNRESET` error. Maybe a data structure thread synchronization issue?

Comment: @GilHamilton I have added the removed part of the code. The fact is that the "random" receiving node never comes out of the "while" block in receiving function, and keeps waiting for others to connect (however, others say they are connected). So, the node never comes out of the "while" block to have a chance to close any socket. And the only one who closes the socket is the "receiveDataHandler" function not the "receiveData_Serial" function. I would be more than happy if you need any more clarifications.

Comment: Still have a hard time matching up code to explanation. For example, you say "the only one who closes the socket is the 'receiveDataHandler'" but I don't see any of the accepted sockets being closed at all -- only the listening one.  A suggestion: if node A says that it's connected to node B, find out what the remote port number is for the connect (`getpeername` on node A). Then go run `netstat -atn` on node B and find out what state that port is in.

Answer (score 0):

```
            for s, ip in connectionInfoList:
                s.shutdown(1)# 0:Further receives are disallowed -- 1: Further  sends are disallow / sends -- 2: Further sends and receives are disallowed.
                s.close()
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

You `shutdown` the connections while some `relayWorker` thread in the `pool` may still be unfinished. Reverse the order:

```
                pool.close()
                pool.join()
                for s, ip in connectionInfoList:
                    s.close()
```